# How can I track multiple shortest paths from one node to another using Dijkstra / Bellman-Ford

Tags: graphs, graph-traversal, weighted-graphs, dijkstras-algorithm

I want to find how many shortest paths are there from Node A to node B.
For example, let's say we have a graph with 3 nodes and 3 connections:
from 1 to 2 weight 5
from 1 to 3 weight 11
from 2 to 3 weight 6
The answer is 2.
Also I should keep track what vertices were visited for every path.
In the example above, I would have 1 -> 3 and 1 -> 2 -> 3
How can I do it?
Both ideas and pseudocodes are welcomed.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: What resources have you consulted?  Standard textbooks describe how to reconstruct a shortest path (using prev pointers).  Which ones have you read?  There is little point in us repeating material that is already widely available in standard resources.

Comment: How, in your variant, do you keep how you reached a node? Beware there may be *many* shortest paths. (Bonus question: how many?) (Effective line breaks in *markdown* /the edit window: append two blanks to the preceding line.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you cannot decide which are the interesting paths until you know the shortest length, a two-pass method is possible: 1) find a shortest path using your favorite algorithm, 2) enumerate all paths from source to destination and report those of that length, for example using DFS. As a micro-optimization, you can leave the partial paths that are longer than the shortest length.